# Convert networkx graph to dot format in python

Tags: python, networkx, dot

I am converting my networkx graph using the following code.

```
nx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot(G,path)
```

It creates a correct dot format which I can visualize later using graphviz interface. However, instead of adding multiple existing lines(Arcs, edges whatever you say), it creates a single (or two if there is an edge in the opposite direction). I just want to have all lines to be preserved in the dot format. How can I do that?

Comment: Is your `networkx` graph (i.e. `G`) a MultiDiGraph or just a DiGraph?

Comment: @Sparky05 Hi, I am also new to networkx, what is the difference?

Comment: A DiGraph is a directed graph, but allows only one edge per direction, e.g. you can't have multiple u->v connections. If you add multiple u->v nodes to a DiGraph, you only overwrite the edge attributes or if you don't have edge attributes, you don't change the graph add all. MultiDiGraph allow multiple edges (in the same direction), check the [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html).

Comment: Original networkx graph is directional and can have multiple lines in the same direction between two vertices. Actually, I draw the G using nx.draw(G, with_labels = True). IT creates a graph like I described. Dot file on the other hand has one line in one direction and it also does not have the edge labels...

Answer (score 1):

The creation of Networkx graph in the first place was not correct. I changed the line  G=nx.DiGraph(directed=True) to  G=nx.MultiDiGraph(directed=True). Now I do not have that problem.